# Best way to make a transformer with a car, so use the shape keys or use the armature for parenting?

Tags: modifiers, armature, vertex-groups, shape-keys

I'd like to make a transformer. I start with a car. There are three ways of doing this:

- using shape keys (my car consists of one object, but more than a single mesh) and keyframe the influences
- use armature (my car consists of more than a single object and each object consists of a single mesh) and parent each object to a bone (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>)
- use armature (my car consists of one object, but more than a single mesh) and parent each vertex group to a bone.

In the 3rd case, what is the best way to achieve this:

- name the vertex group the same as the bone so they are automatically matched and parented
- or use at each bone a *Bone constraint*, use as object 'car', and use the wanted vertex group?

Comment: I'd suggest using an armature, particularly for rotations. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7189/599

Comment: if your meshed don't change "shape", but are only transformed (of course in this case :D ) "shape" keys are not suited... but sometimes there could be is some action (or cheating), doing this sort of things, and some mesh _could_ change (maybe slightly) its shape... in that case you could use both armatures and shapekeys, where is appropriate.